# How to use padKontrol with Ableton Live?

Tags: midi, electronic-music, ableton-live

I have a [Korg padKontrol](http://www.korg.com/us/products/controllers/padkontrol/) midi controller and it is fairly easy to get it going with Ableton Live 9 as a drum trigger.

However, I would like to use it to trigger scenes in session view and generally to control Ableton. Is it possible?

I have found some padKontrol Scenes that I can use Editor Librarian to load into PadKontrol. There are also some als files like Live_KORG.als in padKontrol installation directory, but I have no idea how to make use of those either. What are they for?

Comment: JC just submitted the answer you need, but as for the .als files, those are probably different templates for Ableton that will load Korg's control scheme into Ableton. It's likely not the scheme you want. The best way is to make your own custom map within Ableton as JC described.

Comment: I just thought that I can find some ready-made presets so I don't have to map them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use MIDI mapping. It's the same for any MIDI device.

1. Go to MIDI options and make sure your device or MIDI port is enabled as Remote device.

[image: remote enable]

2. Press the MIDI mapping button, it is in the upper right corner, to the right of the key mapping button (which does the same as the MIDI mapping button, but for your computer keyboard buttons) and to the left of the CPU usage meter.

[image: MIDI mapping]

3. The mapeable parameters will change color. Click the parameter, then press the MIDI pad/key in your controller that you want to assign to the parameter (in this case the scene trigger).

[image: MIDI mapping enabled]

4. Press the MIDI mapping button again (the one in the top right corner) to get out of MIDI mapping mode.

And you are done. That pad in your control surface will now trigger that scene.